# How to update state of a nested object using useState with data collected from a React form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, frontend

I'm new to React. I'm trying to make a simple form to register a user. I'm using useState hook in which the initial state is a nested object. How to update address fields in user object.

My AddUser component is updating name, surname fields but when typing in the form street and city it doesn't update address fields, but adds them as new values.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


export default function AddUser() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName:"",
        lastName:"",
        adres: {
            street:"",
            city:"",
        }
    });

    const onInputChange=(e)=>{
        setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    const onSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/registration/registerUser", user);
        navigate("/");
    };
    
    const {firstName, lastName, street, city} = user

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
                    <h2 className="text-center m-4">Register User</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={(e)=>onSubmit(e)}>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="Firstname" className="form-label">
                                First Name
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type={"text"}
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter your name"
                                name="firstName"
                                value={firstName}
                                onChange={(e)=>onInputChange(e)}
                                required
                            />
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="Lastname" className="form-label">
                                    Last Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type={"text"}
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Enter your lastname"
                                    name="lastName"
                                    value={lastName}
                                    onChange={(e)=>onInputChange(e)}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                        <Link type="submit" className="btn btn-danger mx-2" to="/">
                            Cancel
                        </Link>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const onInputChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setUser((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    adres: {
      ...prevState.adres,
      [name]: value
    }
  }));
};
```

here is html

```
<div className="mb-3">
  <label htmlFor="street" className="form-label">
    Street
  </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter your street"
    name="street"
    value={user.adres.street}
    onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    required
  />
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
  <label htmlFor="city" className="form-label">
    City
  </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter your city"
    name="city"
    value={user.adres.city}
    onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    required
  />
</div>
```

Comment: yes please, ask

Comment: and comment have limited characters, that why your question not completed in above comment.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have one more question.
Now onInputChange updates fields in adres object but user firstName and lastName are added as new fields.
Will it be correct if I will add at the beginning of function onInputChange the following line:

setUser(...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}); 

Will it then properly update also firstName and secondName fields?

Comment: you can use different function  for that or you can set conditions for that